# Compiling issues with boost

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu-12.04, boost-asio

I'm having problems with compiling a program which includes "boost/asio.hpp".
Compiling this program(taken from boost site):

```
example.cpp:
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

with

```
c++ -I path/to/boost_1_55_0 example.cpp -o example
```

works fine. 
But when the program includes:

```
boost/asio.hpp
```

And I'm trying to compile it with:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/boost_1_55_0 example.cpp -o example -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

an executable is generated ,but I'm getting this error when trying to execute "example":

```
./example: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file "libboost_system.so.1.55.0" is located at "/usr/local/lib".
I also tried to compile the program with :

```
g++ -I /usr/local/boost_1_55_0 -L/usr/local/lib example.cpp -o example -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

And got the same error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the linker where to find the library it needs.  I prefer RPATH for this:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/boost_1_55_0 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib example.cpp -o example -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

That bakes `/usr/local/lib` into the executable so `ld` can find it later.  You can see what `ld` will load by running `ldd example` after building.  I bet right now it says "not found" and after adding RPATH it will find the library.

Another option is to set /usr/local/lib as a system search path in your /etc/ld.so.conf, but that's quite a bit more heavyweight.

Answer (score 2):

set up LD_LIBRARY_PATH as export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= path to boost