# Can't link libboost solution on running time

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I installed boost_1_55_0 under `/usr/local/boost_1_55_0`, and in my `makefile` I set the linking flag as:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -I ./ -I/usr/local/boost_1_55_0 -w -std=c++11
LFLAGS = -L./ -lm -lpthread -L/usr/local/boost_1_55_0/lib -lboost_regex
```

I encountered nothing during compile time, but I got:

> ./$(exec): error while loading shared libraries:
>   libboost_regex.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory

I'm pretty sure I cleaned all old files and compiled again, I also granted access to read the files in `usr/local/boost_1_55_0` by `sudo chmod -R +x /usr/local/boost_1_55_0` just in case I banned access to read. However, I still got this error. I also tried to move `boost_1_55_0` in `/usr/lib/` but it does not work either.

I've also read this question: [Compiling issue with boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744537/compiling-issues-with-boost) and tried both solutions under this question, but neither of them works for me. Can someone figure out a different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually cleaned the executable files and compiled it again, and it somehow solved my problem. I am guessing there must be some config in my system messed up so that the executable would invisibly linked to some outdated directory and cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the error implies, your executable is unable to find the shared library. Add the .so file (or all of them, if you want to be safe) that was generated by the boost build process to the same directory where your program's executable is getting generated, and try running the program again.

Comment: This doesn't help actually.